# Receive video files through http on my rails JSON api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, resque, rails-api

So here's the thing. I believe my case is pretty particular at this point, and some help from the experts it's highly advisable.

I have an API built on Rails (3.2.6) and what I want to able to do is receive a video file (mostly .mp4, .avi) and upload it to s3 through a Process Queue (Using Resque).

Now I'm kind of lost on how to do this.  To my understanding, I would be receiving a byte[] (Array of bytes) through the request which is the video and send that as a param to my Resque job in order to upload it (Resque Job params can only be strings, not objects)?

Has anyone had any experience doing this sort of procedure. We're pretty much trying to mimic the http://docs.brightcove.com/en/media/ create_video method. Where a Video object can be created either by sending the direct file in the request or the link the file....

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might be over thinking it. Why can't users just send a post request with the file like an HTML form would do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) gem.  You should allow someone to HTTP POST the file data to your API, and then save that file data on the backend and upload it to S3 using CarrierWave.